# Can I run a Perl script from stdin?

Tags: perl

Suppose I have a Perl script, namely mytest.pl. Can I run it by something like `cat mytest.pl | perl -e`?

The reason I want to do this is that I have a encrypted perl script and I can decrypt it in my c program and I want to run it in my c program. I don't want to write the decrypted script back to harddisk due to secruity concerns, so I need to run this perl script on-the-fly, all in memory.

This question has nothing to do with the `cat` command, I just want to know how to feed perl script to stdin, and let perl interpreter to run it.

Comment: "cat mytest.pl | perl" should work, but why?

Comment: What are you trying to do, and why do you think this is the solution?

Comment: I have an example in Mastering Perl that shows how easy it is to get around what you are trying to do. You only think you have security, but when you send the data outside of your program, you lose control of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
perl < mytest.pl
```

should do the trick in any shell. It invokes perl and feeds the script in via the shell redirection operator `<`.

As pointed out, though, it seems a little unnecessary. Why not start the script with

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

or perhaps

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

? (modified to reflect your `Perl` and/or `env` path)

Note the [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). Whenever I use `cat` I stop and think whether the shell can provide this functionality for me instead.

Comment: If you want to execute stdin, and you want to pass an argument, use perl -- - inputparam < mytest.pl

Comment: Useless Use of Cat Award link is broken, here is the archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20091121155349/http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: Amended with a non-web archive version

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes one needs to execute a perl script and pass it an argument. The STDIN construction `perl input_file.txt < script.pl` won't work. Using the tip from [How to assign a heredoc value to a variable in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167746) we overcome this by using a "here-script":

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -d '' SCRIPT <<'EOS'
$total = 0;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    @line = split "\t";
    $total++;
}

print "Total: $total\n"; 
EOS

perl -e "$SCRIPT" input_file.txt
```

Comment: No need to do that.  Use perl -- - inputparam < script.pl

Answer (score 3):

```
perl mytest.pl
```

should be the correct way. Why are you doing the unnecessary?

Answer (score 2):

```
cat mytest.pl | perl
```

…is all you need. The `-e` switch expects the script as a command line argument.

Comment: See "Useless Cat Award", referenced in Brian's reply.

Comment: The question is about reading from STDIN. I'm assuming the use of cat was an example and the Perl was being generated in a more interesting way.

Comment: Dorward, you are correct. I have updated my question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

`perl` will read the program from `STDIN` if you don't give it any arguments.

So you could theoretically read an encrypted file, decrypt it, and run it, without saving the file anywhere.

---

Here is a sample program:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;

use Crypt::CBC;

my $encrypted = do {
  open my $encrypted_file, '<', 'perl_program.encrypted';
  local $/ = undef;
  <$encrypted_file>;
};

my $key = pack("H16", "0123456789ABCDEF");
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
  '-key'    => $key,
  '-cipher' => 'Blowfish'
);
my $plaintext = $cipher->decrypt($encrypted);

use IPC::Run qw'run';
run [$^X], \$plaintext;
```

To test this program, I first ran this:

```
perl -MCrypt::CBC -e'
  my $a = qq[print "Hello World\n"];
  my $key = pack("H16", "0123456789ABCDEF");
  my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(-key=>$key,-cipher=>"Blowfish");
  my $encrypted = $cipher->encrypt($a);
  print $encrypted;
' > perl_program.encrypted
```

This still won't stop dedicated hackers, but it will prevent most users from looking at the unencrypted program.