# How can I have a newline in a string in sh?

Tags: sh

This

```
STR="Hello\nWorld"
echo $STR
```

produces as output

```
Hello\nWorld
```

instead of

```
Hello
World
```

What should I do to have a newline in a string?

Note: This question is not about *echo*.
I'm aware of `echo -e`, but I'm looking for a solution that allows passing a string (which includes a newline) as an argument to *other* commands that do not have a similar option to interpret `\n`'s as newlines.

Comment: Related: *[Echo newline in Bash prints literal \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/)*

Answer (score 515, accepted):

If you're using Bash, you can use backslash-escapes inside of a specially-quoted `$'string'`. For example, adding `\n`:

```bash
STR=$'Hello\nWorld'
echo "$STR" # quotes are required here!
```

Prints:

```
Hello
World
```

If you're using pretty much any other shell, just insert the newline as-is in the string:

```bash
STR='Hello
World'
```

Bash recognizes a number of other backslash escape sequences in the `$''` string. Here is an excerpt from the Bash manual page:

```
Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to
string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the
ANSI C standard. Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded
as follows:
      \a     alert (bell)
      \b     backspace
      \e
      \E     an escape character
      \f     form feed
      \n     new line
      \r     carriage return
      \t     horizontal tab
      \v     vertical tab
      \\     backslash
      \'     single quote
      \"     double quote
      \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value
             nnn (one to three digits)
      \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal
             value HH (one or two hex digits)
      \cx    a control-x character

The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not
been present.

A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign ($"string") will cause
the string to be translated according to the current locale. If the
current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored. If the
string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.
```

Comment: That's valid bash, but not POSIX sh.

Comment: +1-just a note: export varDynamic="$varAnother1$varAnother2"$'\n'

Comment: on POSIX I would type
`IFS='^J'` and use that. Any other option known?

Comment: This does indeed work with literal strings as the OP asked, but fails as soon as variables are to be substituted: `STR=$"Hello\nWorld"` simply prints `Hello\nWorld`.

Comment: @ssc single quotes, not double

Comment: @ssc there are no variables in your example. Also, this method requires single quotes. Finally, to include interpolated variables you would have to concatenate double-quoted and special-single-quoted strings together. e.g. `H="Hello"; W="World"; STR="${H}"$'\n'"${W}"; echo "${STR}"` will echo "Hello" and "World" on separate lines

Comment: @JDS (and miken32): Thanks for the extra explanation, much appreciated! Makes for ugly code, but works. :-)

Comment: how to have \n in sh? (not bash)

Answer (score 213):

Echo is so nineties and so fraught with perils that its use should result in core dumps no less than 4GB. Seriously, echo's problems were the reason why the Unix Standardization process finally invented the `printf` utility, doing away with all the problems.

So to get a newline in a string, there are two ways:

```
# 1) Literal newline in an assignment.
FOO="hello
world"
# 2) Command substitution.
BAR=$(printf "hello\nworld\n") # Alternative; note: final newline is deleted
printf '<%s>\n' "$FOO"
printf '<%s>\n' "$BAR"
```

There! No SYSV vs BSD echo madness, everything gets neatly printed and fully portable support for C escape sequences. Everybody please use `printf` now for all your output needs and never look back.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I think it provides really good advice. Note, however, that my original question wasn't really about how to get echo to print newlines, but how to get a newline into a shell variable. You show how to do that using printf as well, but I think that the solution from [amphetamachine](http://stackoverflow.com/users/237955/amphetamachine) using `$'string'` is even cleaner.

Comment: Only for a deficient definition of 'clean'. The `$'foo'` syntax is not valid POSIX syntax as of 2013. Many shells will complain.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I get so screwed trying to use bash specific stuff in sh files all too often.

Comment: `BAR=$(printf "hello\nworld\n")` does not print the trailing \n for me

Comment: @Jonny It shouldn't; the shell specification for command substitution says that one or more newlines at the end of the output are deleted. I realize this is unexpected for my example and have edited it to include a newline in the printf.

Comment: @Jens You show how to print a trailing newline after a variable, but how does one preserve the trailing newline WITHIN the variable?  That is to say, I'd like to be able to say: `echo "$BAR" something` and have 'something' show up on a new line.

Comment: @ishmael Then you need to make the newline part of the variable value, like I do with `FOO` (remove `world` to leave only `"` on that line.)

Comment: @Jens Thanks, but I was hoping for a way of doing it using '\n' and not a literal newline (which forces me to type two lines).  Is there any way of making the $(...) evaluation retain the trailing newline?

Comment: @ismael No, `$()` is specified by POSIX as **removing sequences of one or more <newline> characters at the end of the substitution**.

Comment: Well (in bash), try `printf -v var "%s\n\n" "valuea" "valueb"`. It seems to retain the last two `\n`. Clue: `echo -n "$var"|xxd`. :)

Comment: In sh: `var="$(printf "%s\n\n" "vala" "valb" "x")";echo -n "${var%x}" |xxd'`

Comment: That's: add an x at the end and then remove it. And redefine the printf to this new command. [Redefinition](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) and the x trick from [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#content.3D.24.28.3Cfile.29) point 41 of Bash Pitfails.

Comment: What are echo's problems really?

Comment: @TheoYou Echo's problems are that it is unspecified what it does when the first arg is -e, -n or -c and what happens when an arg ends in \c. BSD and SYSV echo behave differently. In a word: echo options are unportable, while printf is fully specified.

Comment: @TheoYou Predictably, there is a separate question with a good answer to that. This is literally my first Google hit for "why is printf preferred over echo": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530203/what-is-more-portable-echo-e-or-using-printf

Comment: Thanks, now I can: `less "$(printf '+&^ INFO\nF')" /var/log/some*.log`

Answer (score 80):

What I did based on the other answers was

```
NEWLINE=$'\n'
my_var="__between eggs and bacon__"
echo "spam${NEWLINE}eggs${my_var}bacon${NEWLINE}knight"

# which outputs:
spam
eggs__between eggs and bacon__bacon
knight
```

Answer (score 49):

I find the `-e` flag elegant and straight forward

```
bash$ STR="Hello\nWorld"

bash$ echo -e $STR
Hello
World
```

If the string is the output of another command, I just use quotes

```
indexes_diff=$(git diff index.yaml)
echo "$indexes_diff"
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers. Also, although it was already there, I've just edited the question to stress the fact that this question is *not* about `echo`.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question

Comment: This totally answers the question I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Worked well for me here. I've used to create a file based on this echo and it generated new lines on the output correctly.

Comment: `echo -e` is notorious for its portability issues. This is less of a Wild West situation now than pre-POSIX, but there is still no reason to prefer `echo -e`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530203/what-is-more-portable-echo-e-or-using-printf

Answer (score 35):

The problem isn't with the shell.  The problem is actually with the `echo` command itself, and the lack of double quotes around the variable interpolation.  You can try using `echo -e` but that isn't supported on all platforms, and one of the reasons `printf` is now recommended for portability.

You can also try and insert the newline directly into your shell script (if a script is what you're writing) so it looks like...

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello
World"
#EOF
```

or equivalently

```
#!/bin/sh
string="Hello
World"
echo "$string"  # note double quotes!
```

Comment: Since this is more or less the canonical question for the non-[Bash question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/) (and this is chronologically the first answer) and most importantly that the search engines like it, perhaps [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3006137/edit) an example for printf? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 22):

1. The only simple alternative is to actually type a new line in the variable:

   ```
   $ STR='new
   line'
   $ printf '%s' "$STR"
   new
   line
   ```

Yes, that means writing <kbd>Enter</kbd> where needed in the code.

2. There are several equivalents to a `new line` character.

   ```
   \n           ### A common way to represent a new line character.
   \012         ### Octal value of a new line character.
   \x0A         ### Hexadecimal value of a new line character.
   ```

But all those require "an interpretation" by some tool ([POSIX printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html)):

```
    echo -e "new\nline"           ### on POSIX echo, `-e` is not required.
    printf 'new\nline'            ### Understood by POSIX printf.
    printf 'new\012line'          ### Valid in POSIX printf.
    printf 'new\x0Aline'       
    printf '%b' 'new\0012line'    ### Valid in POSIX printf.
```

And therefore, the tool is required to build a string with a new-line:

```
    $ STR="$(printf 'new\nline')"
    $ printf '%s' "$STR"
    new
    line
```

3. In some shells, the sequence <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> is a special shell expansion.
   Known to work in ksh93, bash and zsh:

   ```
   $ STR=$'new\nline'
   ```
4. Of course, more complex solutions are also possible:

   ```
   $ echo '6e65770a6c696e650a' | xxd -p -r
   new
   line
   ```

Or

```
    $ echo "new line" | sed 's/ \+/\n/g'
    new
    line
```

Comment: `echo '6e65770a6c696e650a' | xxd -p -r`, now you're just showing off :P

Answer (score 11):

A $ right before single quotation marks '...\n...' as follows, however double quotation marks doesn't work.

```
$ echo $'Hello\nWorld'
Hello
World
$ echo $"Hello\nWorld"
Hello\nWorld
```

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I first wrote this and then stumbled upon this question. I thought this solution wasn't yet posted, and saw that tlwhitec did post a similar answer. Still I'm posting this because I hope it's a useful and thorough explanation.

**Short answer:**

This seems quite a portable solution, as it works on quite some shells (see comment).
This way you can get a real newline into a variable.

The benefit of this solution is that you don't have to use newlines in your source code, so you can indent
your code any way you want, and the solution still works. This makes it robust. It's also portable.

```
# Robust way to put a real newline in a variable (bash, dash, ksh, zsh; indentation-resistant).
nl="$(printf '\nq')"
nl=${nl%q}
```

**Longer answer:**

Explanation of the above solution:

The newline would normally be lost due to command substitution, but to prevent that, we add a 'q' and remove it afterwards. (The reason for the double quotes is explained further below.)

We can prove that the variable contains an actual newline character (0x0A):

```
printf '%s' "$nl" | hexdump -C
00000000  0a  |.|
00000001
```

(Note that the `'%s'` was needed, otherwise printf will translate a literal `'\n'` string into an actual 0x0A character, meaning we would prove nothing.)

Of course, instead of the solution proposed in this answer, one could use this as well (but...):

```
nl='
'
```

... but that's less robust and can be easily damaged by accidentally indenting the code, or by forgetting to outdent it afterwards, which makes it inconvenient to use in (indented) functions, whereas the earlier solution is robust.

Now, as for the double quotes:
The reason for the double quotes `"` surrounding the command substitution as in `nl="$(printf '\nq')"` is that you can then even prefix the variable assignment with the `local` keyword or builtin (such as in functions), and it will still work on all shells, whereas otherwise the `dash` shell would have trouble, in the sense that dash would otherwise lose the 'q' and you'd end up with an empty 'nl' variable (again, due to command substitution).
That issue is better illustrated with another example:

```
dash_trouble_example() {
    e=$(echo hello world) # Not using 'local'.
    echo "$e" # Fine. Outputs 'hello world' in all shells.

    local e=$(echo hello world) # But now, when using 'local' without double quotes ...:
    echo "$e" # ... oops, outputs just 'hello' in dash,
              # ... but 'hello world' in bash and zsh.

    local f="$(echo hello world)" # Finally, using 'local' and surrounding with double quotes.
    echo "$f" # Solved. Outputs 'hello world' in dash, zsh, and bash.

    # So back to our newline example, if we want to use 'local', we need
    # double quotes to surround the command substitution:
    # (If we didn't use double quotes here, then in dash the 'nl' variable
    # would be empty.)
    local nl="$(printf '\nq')"
    nl=${nl%q}
}
```

Practical example of the above solution:

```
# Parsing lines in a for loop by setting IFS to a real newline character:

nl="$(printf '\nq')"
nl=${nl%q}

IFS=$nl

for i in $(printf '%b' 'this is line 1\nthis is line 2'); do
    echo "i=$i"
done

# Desired output:
# i=this is line 1
# i=this is line 2

# Exercise:
# Try running this example without the IFS=$nl assignment, and predict the outcome.
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm no bash expert, but this one worked for me:

```
STR1="Hello"
STR2="World"
NEWSTR=$(cat << EOF
$STR1

$STR2
EOF
)
echo "$NEWSTR"
```

I found this easier to formatting the texts.

Comment: Good old [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells). And it's probably POSIX compliant too!

Comment: The quotes around `$NEWSTR` in `echo "$NEWSTR"` are important here

Comment: @Shadi, thanks! I made many attempts in other solutions to output string, but it didn't split into lines, until I saw your comment.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't ideal, but I had written a lot of code and defined strings in a way similar to the method used in the question. The accepted solution required me to refactor a lot of the code so instead, I replaced every `\n` with `"$'\n'"` and this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Those picky ones that need just the newline and despise the multiline code that breaks indentation, could do:

```
IFS="$(printf '\nx')"
IFS="${IFS%x}"
```

Bash (and likely other shells) gobble all the trailing newlines after command substitution, so you need to end the `printf` string with a non-newline character and delete it afterwards. This can also easily become a oneliner.

```
IFS="$(printf '\nx')" IFS="${IFS%x}"
```

> I know this is two actions instead of one, but my indentation and portability OCD is at peace now :) I originally developed this to be able to split newline-only separated output and I ended up using a modification that uses `\r` as the terminating character. That makes the newline splitting work even for the dos output ending with `\r\n`.
>
> ```
> IFS="$(printf '\n\r')"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Ubuntu 17.10) your example just works as desired, both when typed from the command line (into `sh`) and when executed as a `sh` script:

```
[bash]§ sh
$ STR="Hello\nWorld"
$ echo $STR
Hello
World
$ exit
[bash]§ echo "STR=\"Hello\nWorld\"
> echo \$STR" > test-str.sh
[bash]§ cat test-str.sh 
STR="Hello\nWorld"
echo $STR
[bash]§ sh test-str.sh 
Hello
World
```

I guess this answers your question: it just works.  (I have not tried to figure out details such as at what moment exactly the substitution of the newline character for `\n` happens in `sh`).

However, i noticed that this same script would behave differently when executed *with `bash`* and would print out `Hello\nWorld` instead:

```
[bash]§ bash test-str.sh
Hello\nWorld
```

I've managed to get the desired output with `bash` as follows:

```
[bash]§ STR="Hello
> World"
[bash]§ echo "$STR"
```

Note the double quotes around `$STR`. This behaves identically if saved and run as a `bash` script.

The following also gives the desired output:

```
[bash]§ echo "Hello
> World"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't really happy with any of the options here. This is what worked for me.

```sh
str=$(printf "%s" "first line")
str=$(printf "$str\n%s" "another line")
str=$(printf "$str\n%s" "and another line")
```

Comment: That's a very tedious way to write `str=$(printf '%s\n' "first line" "another line" "and another line")` (the shell will conveniently (or not) trim any final newlines from the command substitution). Several answers here already promote `printf` in various forms so I'm not sure this adds any value as a separate answer.

Comment: It is for short strings, but if you want to keep things tidy and each line is actually 60 characters long, then it's a tidy way of doing it. Given that it is the solution I eventually went with, it does add something, if not for you, then for myself in the future when I undoubtedly return.

Comment: Even for long strings I prefer `printf '%s\n' "first line" \ ` (newline, indent) `'second line'` etc. See also `printf -v str` for assigning to a variable without spawning a subshell.