# What is more portable? echo -e or using printf?

Tags: bash, compatibility

I'm currently writing a bash testing framework, which requires to be as portable as possible.

So, at one point, I had to print a leading newline followed by some text which contains several expanded variables. This is the solution I've used.

```
echo -e "\n$number_of_specs ${units}, $number_of_specs_failed failed"
```

This seems okay but I'm not sure how portable that is compared to printing out the line using e.g. `printf`?

Any ideas or hints where I could find some references?

Comment: By 'portable', do you mean portable between various shells (which means not bash) or between various bash versions?

Comment: Not clear how a bash testing framework needs to be compatible with anything but bash. I guess maybe your point is that some OS's don't have printf, and as such is really not part of bash, but provides incompatibilites? Have you looked at how much work compatibility costs in the implementation of autoconf and ./configure? Why not just some tests at top, `if [[ ! -f /bin/printf ]] ; echo -e "please have printf installed before running the rest of this script" ; fi ` ?? Good luck.

Comment: I believe `printf` is technically still more portable because the default `xpg_echo` behavior can vary between platforms even within Bash (so you can set it explicitly if you really wanted.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`printf` is more portable. It should always be preferred over `echo -e`. If targeting bash/zsh/ksh specifically, `echo $'...'` is also ok. If targeting zsh or ksh specifically, `print` is ok.

- http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq.html#Q0b
- http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_16

POSIX (last link) also discusses `echo -n` problems, which should also be avoided. Basically, never use options to `echo`, and for portability, use printf.)

Answer (score 1):

The most portable (in terms of portability to ancient systems without printf) solution for leading newlines is obviously

```
echo
echo "$number_of_specs ${units}, $number_of_specs_failed failed"
```