# Using the %b directive in bash's printf

Tags: bash, printf

I've come across a few answers/comments on this site that using the `%b` directive `bash`'s `printf` command is not recommended. Is this true? If so, why? It seems better than using `echo` with the `-e` option since `echo` won't print strings that begin with a valid option name.

Comment: This might help: [What is more portable? echo -e or using printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11530203/3776858)

Comment: Of course, `printf` with `%b` isn't any more portable than `echo -e`,  because both are `bash` extensions.

Comment: @chepner are you sure?  `%b` is document [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) in POSIX, number 7 under EXTENDED DESCRIPTION

Comment: Huh. The `bash` man page describes it as an extension; wonder if that is old wording that was never updated?

Comment: @EricRenouf It is indeed listed there, but at least in `dash` running `printf "%b" "\x61"` outputs `\x61` instead of the desired `a`. So I wouldn't rely on it being present in general.