# How to list subdirectories with white space in their names in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I've found a few similar questions to this but surprisingly none of them work for me.

I have this written in a script:

`for d in $(ls -d "$1"); do
echo $d
done`

$1 is the parent directory for which I wish to print out the list of subdirectories for, however, running this prints out, for example, a directory named "dir with spaces" as 3 words on separate lines.

Comment: I must say - I have never come across a problem like this in my career so far; usually for something seemingly simple but irritating, I will have to spend 10-30 mins maximum doing research and i'll find a solution, but this one has really got me!

Comment: Try the find command.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020), and also ["Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`"`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: If you just want directories, you can use a glob ending with `/`: `for d in "$1"/*/; do echo "$d"; done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use shell globbing instead of process substitution, which doesn't suffer from word expansion problem:

```sh
# to include dotfiles and not iterate empty directory
shopt -s dotglob nullglob

for d in "$1"/*; do
    echo "$d"
done
```

Or you can resort to pretty common `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` pattern.

Comment: Use `shopt -s nullglob` to handle empty directories correctly.  `printf '%s\n' "$d"` is safer then `echo "$d"` (see [What is more portable? echo -e or using printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11530203/4154375)).

Comment: Everything goes well except I get "shopt: not found"

Comment: actually I just realised that's because I was running the script with 'sh' instead of 'bash'. In that case this works pretty well, thanks!