# Bash "-n" argument not recognized by script when using "$@"

Tags: bash, echo

I am using a bash script that expects command line arguments preceded by a dash followed by a file name:

```
./script -abc file_name
```

In the script, I try to print out all of the arguments to the script using:

`echo "$@"`

which displays:

```
-abc file_name
```

which is expected. Everything prints fine except for when I use the letter "n" by itself, i.e.:

`./script -n file_name`

The resulting echo statement inside the script only prints out the *file_name* argument and not the "-n" argument at all. This behavior only occurs with the letter "n" by itself. When I try "-nx" or 'n' with any other letter(s) the echo statement prints out fine...

Why does this echo statement not work with "-n" by itself?

Comment: `echo -- "$@"` will print `--` as well. Use `printf` as Jeb suggested.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530203/what-is-more-portable-echo-e-or-using-printf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-n` or `-e` are valid options for the `echo` command.

Therefore it's consumed by the echo command and only the remaining text is shown.
That's a known problem of `echo` and to avoid this you can use `printf`.

```
printf "%s\n" "$*"
```

Comment: Specifically, for *non-standard* implementations of `echo`.  POSIX `echo` doesn't interpret any options, but many platforms have "extended" vesions that behave differently.  That's irrelevant to the fix, which is to use `printf` (though not like that, unless you want a newline between each argument; an exact equivalent is more like `printf '%s\n' "$*"`).

Comment: @TobySpeight You are right, I corrected it from `$@` to `$*` now

Answer (score 0):

Some interesting behaviour here:

when

```sh
$ set -- -n foo
```

then you have observed that you don't see the "-n" argument, nor the trailing newline:

```sh
$ echo "$@" | od -c
0000000   f   o   o
0000003
```

but using the `"$*"` parameter expansion does give the expected results:

```
$ echo "$*" | od -c
0000000   -   n       f   o   o  \n
0000007
```

Without reading the source code, I suspect that when `echo` is given only a single argument, it knows there are no options to be parsed.

Nevertheless, use `printf` so you have complete control over your output.