# How to display newline in ssh

Tags: linux, shell, newline, sh

I'm trying to do the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh user@server "echo \"Test \n for newline\""
```

This displays:

```
test \n for newline
```

How do I get the shell to interpret `\n` as an actual newline?

Comment: `echo` disables interpretation of backslash escapes by default.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I have a newline in a string in sh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005963/how-can-i-have-a-newline-in-a-string-in-sh)

Comment: Note that the accepted answer for the linked duplicate is specific to `bash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `-e` option, e.g., `echo -e "Test \n for newline"`.

If your `echo` doesn't have a `-e` option, then I'd use `printf`. It's widely available and it does not have nearly as many variations in it's implementations.

Comment: this doesn't work.  Man page says `-n Do not print the trailing newline character.`  That's the only option I have.  The description in the beginning does say, "The echo utility writes any specified operands, separated by single `(` ')` characters and followed by a newline `(`\n')` character, to the standard output."

Comment: If your `echo` doesn't have a `-e` option, then I'd use `printf`. It's widely available and it does not have nearly as many variations in it's implementations.

Answer (score 2):

For greater portability, use `printf` instead of `echo`.

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh user@server 'printf "Test \n for newline"'
```

According to the POSIX standard, `echo` should process `\n` as a newline character. The `bash` built-in `echo` does not, unless you supply the `-e` option.

Answer (score 1):

Just use one of

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh user@server "echo -e \"Test \n for newline\""
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh user@server 'echo  -e "Test \n for newline"'
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh user@server "echo  -e 'Test \n for newline'"
```

or even

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh user@server "echo 'Test 
 for newline'"
```

All of those will display

```
Test 
 for newline
```

(note the trailing space after the first line and the leading space before the second one - I just copied your code)

Answer (score 0):

Before exectuning ssh command update the IFS environment variable with new line character.

```
IFS='                                  
'
```

Store the ssh command output to a varaible

```
CMD_OUTPUT=$(ssh userName@127.0.0.1 'cat /proc/meminfo')
```

iterate the output per line

```
for s in $CMD_OUTPUT; do echo "$s"; done
```