# Echo multi-line variable content over ssh

Tags: variables, ssh, echo

I'm trying to echo multiline variable over ssh, but the second line gets executed as a command.

`msg="Hello World; Hello World2"; echo $msg; ssh -q newhost "echo "$msg""`

Output:

```
Hello World; Hello World2

Hello World

bash: Hello: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason it needs to be a multi-line variable? why not send two distinct messages?

```
    msg="Hello World"; msg2="Hello World2"; echo $msg; ssh -q localhost "echo "$msg""$msg2""
```

works fine

echo -e  will let you interpret escaped characters like \n which you should use instead of semicolon ;

Comment: If you are set on multiline I just found out that

        echo -e Hello\nWorld

May give you what you need.

Comment: msg="Hello World\nHello World2"; echo -e $msg;

Comment: The example I provided in the topic is a brief simplified version of what I'm trying to do. I actually have a file with number of commands there. I assign content from that file to a variable and trying to echo it on different host over ssh. That is why it should be in one multiline variable. But instead of echoing it all commands from the file get executed.

Comment: Here is another example: A="hostname;hostname"; echo -e "$A";
 
ssh -q newhost01 "echo -e $A" hostname;hostname hostname newhost01

Comment: can you use the newline character instead of the semi colon? \n instead of ;

Comment: A="hostname\nhostname"; echo -e "$A"; ssh localhost  "echo -e \"$A\"";

Comment: Next time try searching for your answer on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148688/how-to-display-newline-in-ssh