# Git Post Merge Hook does not recognize valid commands

Tags: git, bash

Here is my post-merge hook script. Trying to do some cleanup/setup on post merge based on the currentBranch. Not getting the output i expect

```
# !/bin/bash 

git branch --contains $2
curbranch1=$(git branch --contains $2)
echo  $curbranch1
curbranch2=$(echo "$curbranch1"|grep "*")
echo  $curbranch2


#output

Switched to branch 'develop'
* develop
NET SRC-Fiery-PF-PS VB6Dev bin develop
NET SRC-Fiery-PF-PS VB6Dev bin develop
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to assign a value to a variable without space around the equal sign:

```
currentBranch=$(git branch --contains $2)
```

> `NET SRC-Fiery-PF-PS VB6Dev bin develop        <--Should match previous line?`

It means the newline is not kept by default.
Try it in two steps:

```
currentBranch=$(git branch --contains $2)
currentBranch=$(echo "$currentBranch"|grep "*")
```

See also "[How can I have a newline in a string in sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3005963/6309)"

Even in one step, it works:

```
#!/bin/sh

n=$(git branch --contains @|grep "*")
echo "$n"
```

Comment: Thanks. that error went away.

#!/bin/bash 


git branch --contains $2 | grep "*"
curbranch=$(git branch --contains $2 | grep "*")

echo $curbranch

#output

Switched to branch 'develop'
* develop
NET SRC-Fiery-PF-PS VB6Dev bin develop

Look at the 3rd line. That should exactly match what i see in the 2nd line. #develop

Comment: @user3924036 I agree, it should work, provided you don't add space around the equal when assigning `curbranch`. Edit your question with your new script and issue: that will be easier to read.

Comment: @user3924036 I have edited my answer to address your entirely new question.

Comment: Sorry. no change..Please see my latest script and output.

Comment: @user3924036 see my edited answer. Try it with `#!/bin/sh`