# python class usage without a new line for python -c '...'?

Tags: python

When defining a class in Python, why does the class usage need to be in a new line? This becomes a bit annoying when trying to run python programs from a string (`python -c '....'`) because I can't define and use the class on the same line. Is there a way to achieve this?

For example, the following fails:

```
$ cat class_play.py
class ClassA(): pass; a = 3; print(a); print(ClassA)
$ class ClassA(): pass; a = 3; print(a); print(ClassA)
$ python class_play.py
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class_play.py", line 1, in <module>
    class ClassA(): pass; a = 3; print(a); print(ClassA)
  File "class_play.py", line 1, in ClassA
    class ClassA(): pass; a = 3; print(a); print(ClassA)
NameError: name 'ClassA' is not defined
```

but using the class in a new line works:

```
$ cat class_play.py
class ClassA(): pass; a = 3; print(a);
print(ClassA)
$ python class_play.py
3
<class '__main__.ClassA'>
```

Comment: why do you want to pass complex programs as a single line?

Comment: If you need a class, you should probably pull things out into a script instead of using `-c`.

Comment: If it's all on a single line how does the interpreter know that `print(ClassA)` is not still part of the class definition?

Comment: @0x5453 I agree, but I wanted to quickly test some things

Comment: @TBurgis good point :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use newlines, the command line is not limited to a single line:

```
python -c "
class Foo:
    pass
print(Foo())
"
```

or just insert [`\n` sequences in a `$'...'` string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005963/how-can-i-have-a-newline-in-a-string-in-sh)

```
python -c $'class Foo:\n    pass\nprint(Foo())'
```

Using semi-colons, you can only add more [simple statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html), and they all fall within the [same compound statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html) if you started the line with one. You can't use these to define methods or expect a `class` statement to have completed, you are *still in the `class` definition*.

Comment: perfect thanks! I missed the fact that I was still in the class definition :)