# How can I have a newline in a string in fish shell?

Tags: string, line-breaks, fish

Is same question as
[How can I have a newline in a string in sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005963/how-can-i-have-a-newline-in-a-string-in-sh)
but in fish shell.

In bash we have:

`$'this is line\nthis is another line'`

who produces the expected result, but in fish this doesnt works.

fish has a similar way to do this?

**Edit 1:**

has the literal method wisely mentioned by the faho:

`'this is line
this is another line'`

But i'm really curious about the existence of a method keeping reference for `\n` as line break like in shell.

I want to know if I can use this string `"this is a line\nthis is another line"` making sure that the fish will consider `\n` as a line break and not a literal.

Comment: Amusingly, the fish design doc [describes `$''` as "silly"](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/design.html#ortho)

Comment: Many Thank's Amusingly, now I understand the position of fish shell about this.

Answer (score 9):

1. Fish replaces `\n` outside of quotes with a newline, so you can stop and restart the quotes (note no "$" before the quotes):

'this is line'\n'this is another line'

2. Fish follows quotes across lines, so you can include a literal newline:

`'this is line
this is another line'`

Comment: thanks for your time with this answer.
i can use with this way in shell too.
have another way to do this keeping '\n' like in shell?

Comment: No, you can't do it this way in "shell". POSIX-like shells do not interpret `\n` outside of `$''` - `echo 'a'\n'b'` prints `anb`.

Comment: There is also, in both fish and POSIX shells, `echo -e`, which will interpret backslash-escapes in strings, so `echo -e 'a\nb'` will also print a, a newline and b. I'd recommend just using the first way I gave you, as that's available regardless of what you're passing the argument to.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `echo -e` (*Enable interpretation of backslash escapes*), as pointed out by @faho in his comment:

```
$ echo -e "## Foo\nBar"
## Foo
Bar
```

From `man echo`:

> ### Escape sequences
>
> ```
>    If -e is used, the following sequences are recognized:
>
>    o \ backslash
>
>    o \a alert (BEL)
>
>    o \b backspace
>
>    o \c produce no further output
>
>    o \e escape
>
>    o \f form feed
>
>    o \n new line
>
>    o \r carriage return
>
>    o \t horizontal tab
>
>    o \v vertical tab
>
>    o \0NNN byte with octal value NNN (1 to 3 digits)
>
>    o \xHH byte with hexadecimal value HH (1 to 2 digits)
> ```

Answer (score -3):

Edit your `config.fish` file. 
Example in Ubuntu `sudo nano /etc/fish/config.fish`
Prompt function is what controls the appearance of the fish terminal. Paste this code:

```
# Put system-wide fish configuration entries here
# or in .fish files in conf.d/
# Files in conf.d can be overridden by the user
# by files with the same name in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fish/conf.d

# This file is run by all fish instances.
# To include configuration only for login shells, use
# if status --is-login
#    ...
# end
# To include configuration only for interactive shells, use
# if status --is-interactive
#   ...
# end
#

function fish_prompt -d "Write out the prompt"
    # change output color
    set -U fish_color_command             '2cff8f' -o

    # Aliases
    alias cls='clear'

    # Prompt
    printf '%s@%s%s%s%s\n@>' (whoami) (hostname | cut -d . -f 1) \
                    (set_color $fish_color_cwd) (prompt_pwd) (set_color normal)
end
```

Comment: I guess the gist is to do `printf 'first line\nsecond line'`