# how to pass a multi-line indented script as a string to python interpreter (-c)

Tags: python, string, interpreter

If I do:

```
python -c 'print("Hello");print("Hello") '

python -c 'print("Hello")'
```

It works as expected. However,

```
python -c 'print("Hello") \n print("Hello") '
```

Fails.

```
File "<string>", line 1
    print("Hello") \n print("Hello") 
                                    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

How to handle multi-line (and indented) python code using the -c option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\n` is treated as *two* characters (backslash, the character `n`) by the shell, and that's invalid syntax in Python, so you get the error.

To fix this in Bash, use [`$'string'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005963/how-can-i-have-a-newline-in-a-string-in-sh):

```
forcebru$ python -c $'print("Hello") \nprint("Hello") '
Hello
Hello
forcebru$
```

Note that the space after the newline (`\n print`) will count as invalid indentation (now by Python, not the shell), so I removed it.

Comment: How can I apply this with subprocess.check_output() ?

Comment: How exactly are you planning to use this with `subprocess`? And also why? You can execute Python code right from within Python, no need for external programs. See `exec`, for example. But be careful! `exec` will execute any Python code, so don't use it to run code provided by the user, although there are ways to sanitize the input and the runtime environment.

Comment: unfortunately I need subprocess as the execution must start from a remote interpreter....I will accept your answer anyway