# Two seemingly identical strings with newlines not equal

Tags: bash, sed, newline

I am trying to convert a list of quoted strings, separated by commas, into list of strings separated by newlines using bash and sed.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

comma_to_newline() {
  sed -En $'s/[ \t]*"([^"]*)",?[ \t]*/\\1\\\n/gp'
}

input='"one","two","three"'
expected="one\ntwo\nthree" 
result="$( echo "${input}" | comma_to_newline )"

echo "Expected: <${expected}>"
echo "Result: <${result}>"

if [ "${result}" = "${expected}" ]; then
  echo "EQUAL!"
else
  echo "NOT EQUAL!"
fi
```

And the output I am getting is:

```
Expected: <one
two
three>
Result: <one
two
three>
NOT EQUAL!
```

I know it has something to do with the newlines characters, but I can't work out what. If I replace the newlines with some other string, such as `XXX`, it works fine and bash reports the strings as being equal.

Comment: That's really what you get for the Expected printout? Not `Expected: <one\ntwo\nthree>`?

Comment: I copied the script and my `Expected` agrees with Shawn's.

Comment: Yup, that is what I get. I am running: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release-(x86_64-apple-darwin18)` on Mac OS. But getting `<one\ntwo\nthree>` on `GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)` on Debian 

Comment: I was expecting the problem to be with my sed function, but it turns out it was a problem with my expected string and an old version bash! `expected=$'one\ntwo\nthree'` works fine!

Comment: Note that your variable `expected` does not contain any newline character. You can verify this by writing a `xxd <<<$expected` just after setting the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompted by the comments on my question, I managed to work out what was going on. I was so focussed on coming up with a working sed expression and ensuring that `result` was correct, that I failed to noticed that the `expected` string was incorrect.

1. In order to use `\n` newlines in a bash string, you have to use the `$'one\ntwo\nthree'` syntax - see [How can I have a newline in a string in sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005963/how-can-i-have-a-newline-in-a-string-in-sh) for other solutions.
2. I was developing against bash version 3.2.57 (the version that comes with Mac OS 10.14.6). When assigning a variable using `expected="one\ntwo\nthree"` then echoing it, they were being displayed as newlines in the console. Newer versions of bash display these strings as escaped - so I assume it is a bug that has been fixed in later versions of bash.

Answer (score 0):

For diagnosing seemingly identical strings, try combining side-by-side `diff` output with a one char per line `hexdump` format.   Replace:

```
else
  echo "NOT EQUAL!"
fi
```

...with:

```
else
    echo "NOT EQUAL!"
    diff -y \
    <(hexdump -v  -e '/1  "%_ad#  "' -e '/1 " _%_u\_\n"' <<< "${expected}") \
    <(hexdump -v  -e '/1  "%_ad#  "' -e '/1 " _%_u\_\n"' <<< "${result}")
fi
```

Comment: This would be a good answer if there were weird invisible / unicode characters involved. But my problem turned out to be because what bash was printing to stdout was different to its internal representation. And I suspect an old bug in Bash 3.2.57.

Comment: @njh, You seem to have nailed it down, so please consider [answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/334345).  Re _"...a good answer **if**..."_: either way, answers like this help test whether such an *"if"* is true or false.

Answer (score 0):

There is extra new line character `\n` in string returing from your function.

Octal dump

```
$echo '"one","two","three"' | sed -En $'s/[ \t]*"([^"]*)",?[ \t]*/\\1\\\n/gp' | od -c 
0000000   o   n   e  \n   t   w   o  \n   t   h   r   e   e  \n  \n
0000017
$echo "one\ntwo\nthree"  |  od -c 
0000000   o   n   e   \   n   t   w   o   \   n   t   h   r   e   e  \n
0000020
$
```

Also, use `echo -e`

```
$echo "one\ntwo\nthree"  
one\ntwo\nthree
$echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree"  
one
two
three
$
```

From `man` page

> -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes