# base64 decoding fails when assigning bash variable?

Tags: bash, base64, variable-assignment, file-encodings

I have failed to understand the following behaviour. First encoding that seems ok to me:

```
$ echo -n "Cg==" | base64 -d | xxd
00000000: 0a
$ echo -n "Cgo=" | base64 -d | xxd
00000000: 0a0a
```

When I assign the decoding to a variable I lose LF in the process.

```
$ VAR=$(echo -n "Cg==" | base64 -d)
$ echo -n $VAR | xxd
$ VAR=$(echo -n "Cgo=" | base64 -d)
$ echo -n $VAR | xxd
$
```

That is I do not get anything back other then null ("") instead of 0a and 0a0a respectively. What am I missing? Mistake in the example? Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: You always loose LF with this syntax, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005963/how-can-i-have-a-newline-in-a-string-in-sh).

Comment: Thanks,  read the post and one of the answers seems to fit the above: 
@ismael No, $() is specified by POSIX as removing sequences of one or more <newline> characters at the end of the substitution. – Jens Jun 3 '14 at 8:21

Comment: I have to rethink my demo code and possibly code it directly in a suitable non-shell language.