# How do I add newline character at end of lines in blockquote for printing?

Tags: bash, macos, bash4

I'm using MacOS and Bash 4.4.23.

I want to be able to have a long blockquote in a single string for a help dialogue and
print that in the program.

Suppose I have a string in var `help`

```
help='Searches a user to
see if he exists.'

help2='Searches a user to\n
see if he exists.'

echo $help # all one line
echo $help2 # all one line (with literal \n)

printf $help # prints 'Searches'
printf $help2 # same ^
```

I also tried

```
help3=$'Searches a user\n
to see if he exists.'
```

but I still don't get my expected results.

What I want to be printed:

```
Searches a user to
see if he exists.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$help` is set correctly; what needs fixing is when it's expanded. As a rule of thumb you should almost always quote variables when they're expanded. Doing so here will preserve the embedded newline(s).

```
help='Searches a user to
see if he exists.'

echo "$help"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through for string splitting options, I found I could do this

```
help='Searches a user
to see if he exists.'

IFS=$'\n'

printf '%s\n' $help

unset IFS
```

you can also do a `for line in $help; do echo $line done` instead of the using the `printf` command.

src: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting

src2: [How can I have a newline in a string in sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005963/how-can-i-have-a-newline-in-a-string-in-sh)