# How to use python -c "code here" with newlines?

Tags: python, bash, cmd, command-line

The command

```
python -c "print('hello')"
```

runs the code inside the quotes successfully, both in Linux (bash) and Windows (cmd.exe).

**But how to pass code with newlines, with `python -c`?**

Example: both

```
python -c "for i in range(10): if i % 2 == 0: print('hello')"
python -c "for i in range(10):\n    if i % 2 == 0:\n        print('hello')"
```

fail.

---

Example use case: I need to send a SSH command (with paramiko) to execute a short Python code on a remote server, so I need to pass one command like
`ssh.exec_command('python -c "..."')`.

Comment: you could use a `$'foo bar'` string in bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bash's [`$'foo'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3182519/5923139) string syntax to get newlines:

```
python -c $'for i in range(10):\n if i % 2 == 0:\n  print("hello")'
```

(I'm using single space indents here)

For windows, you really should be using powershell, which has `` `n `` as a newline:

```
python -c "for i in range(10):`n if i % 2 == 0:`n  print('hello')"
```

In cmd.exe, it seems that you can use `^` to escape a newline, however I'm unable to test this currently so you should [refer to this question's answers](https://superuser.com/q/150116).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `bash` *"heredoc"* (also available `ksh`, and POSIX shells):

```
python <<EOF
import numpy as np
print(dir(np))
EOF
```

Comment: @Basj Maybe consider updating your question so it better represents what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be with `exec()`, what make strings executable. It looks bad, but it works.

```
python -c "exec(\"for i in range(10):\n if i % 2 == 0:\n  print('hello')\")"
```

Answer (score 0):

While not using `-c` it is worth mentioning that, if using `Bash`, you can pipe echoed code directly to `python`.

```
echo -e 'for i in range(10):\n if i % 2 == 0:\n  print("hello")' | python
```

Following Aplet123's lead and using using single space indents.