# System.get_env in elixir and new line (\n)

Tags: shell, elixir, escaping, newline, backslash

```
~ ❯ export TEST_KEY='hello\nworld' && iex

iex(1)> System.get_env("TEST_KEY")
"hello\\nworld"
```

When running `System.get_env/1` on a string with `\n` it inserts an extra backslash, any way of preventing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not insert anything, it fairly reads the environment variable and, because backslashes are to be escaped in double-quotes, prints it as you see.

What you think is “new line” is nothing but the escape sequence. Here is an excerpts from e. g. `echo` man:

```sh
  -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
  -E     disable interpretation of backslash escapes
```

The default behaviour in raw shell:

```sh
❯ echo -E 'hello\nworld'
hello\nworld
```

The fact, that you see a new line there in `echo` by default, or whatever is **a side effect by the interpreter**, whoever this interpreter is. The value itself contains a backslash and `n` ASCII symbols, and no magic besides.

---

That said, if one wants to have *new lines* in place of `\n` sequence in the value, one must apply the escaping themselves.

```elixir
"TEST_KEY"
|> System.get_env()
|> to_string() # to NOT raise on absent value, redundant
|> String.replace("\\n", "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a shell question, not an elixir question. See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005963/how-can-i-have-a-newline-in-a-string-in-sh) that shows how to set a new line in an environment variable in bash. Using it from elixir:

```sh
$ TEST_KEY=$'hello\nworld' elixir -e 'IO.puts(System.get_env("TEST_KEY"))'
hello
world
```