# consul-template expand new lines from env var

Tags: consul, go-templates, hcl, consul-template

In consul-template I want to pass a ENV var with with new lines that will be expanded so `"hello\nworld"` is shown as:

```
hello
world
```

command:
`VARIABLE="hell\nworld" consul-template -template "in.tpl:out.txt" -once && cat out.txt`

template file: `{{ env "VARIABLE" }}`

however I am getting

```
hello\nworld
```

If I debug the template I am showed the `\n` has been escaped to `\\n`:

`{{ env "VARIABLE" | spew_dump }}`

```
"hello\\nworld"
```

Answer (score 1):

### In `consul-template`

```
{{ env "VARIABLE" | replaceAll "\\n" "\n" }}
```

Given the new-line is as a C-Escape `\n` in a golang double quoted string literal, there is the [`replaceAll` consul template function](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/blob/main/docs/templating-language.md#replaceall)<sup>1</sup> readily available (similar to `env`) to replace `\n` with *U+000A New Line (Nl) line feed (lf) , end of line (eol) , LF*.

This is the format as shown by the `spew_dump` in question.

Note that this replaces `\n` only, not `\r` nor the other escape sequences.

---

### In Shell (earlier)

There is no `\n` C-Escape in double-quoted strings like `"hello\nworld"` , but `printf(1)` has it - or - if your shell supports them, `$''` strings (bash, zsh/z-shell).

Compare with *[How can I have a newline in a string in sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3005963/367456)*.

Examples:

**Example #1: `$''` quoted string**

```
VARIABLE=$'hello\nworld' consul-template -template "in.tpl:out.txt" -once && cat out.txt
```

**Example #2: `printf(1)`**

```
VARIABLE="$(printf "hello\nworld")" consul-template -template "in.tpl:out.txt" -once && cat out.txt
```

Mind that command substitution (`$(...)`) may remove a trailing newline.

---

1. https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/blob/378ee4bf907cae0d41eebf6a854f5539a7de1987/template/funcs.go#L1173-L1177

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to get the newline inside th of the in.tml file rather than modify it in the variable def. These values could come from env vars or different data sources.

Comment: @henry.oswald: Ah, if you don't want to change early in the environment variables, you can replace within the template. I'd suggest `replaceAll` in my edit. The first double-slash is by intention as necessary, comare with the spew output.

Comment: thanks, ideally i wouldn't have todo find replaces to insert this string. Is it possible to these variables without backslash being escaped?

Comment: Sure, that is the "In Shell (earlier)" section, earlier not only in time of the answer but also _before_ passing it into the template ;).  What are the different data-sources? Already in the environment or probably env files? Please give a bit more context.