# Why is Heroku crashing on a simple streamlit app?

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to host a simple streamlit test app on Heroku for the first time. The app works well on local host, but it crashes on Heroku (code h10).

The full h10 error logs tail is attached. The Github link to the files is here: https://github.com/antonysama/waskasoo-app.

```
    2020-06-22T23:51:43.163645+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh setup.sh && streamlit run waskasoo_app.py`
2020-06-22T23:51:45.701733+00:00 app[web.1]: “
2020-06-22T23:51:45.701797+00:00 app[web.1]: setup.sh: 3: setup.sh: [server]: not found
2020-06-22T23:51:45.701832+00:00 app[web.1]: setup.sh: 4: setup.sh: headless: not found
2020-06-22T23:51:45.701871+00:00 app[web.1]: setup.sh: 6: setup.sh: port: not found
2020-06-22T23:51:45.701981+00:00 app[web.1]: setup.sh: 7: setup.sh: “: not found
2020-06-22T23:51:45.756036+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-06-22T23:51:45.804273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-22T23:51:45.806829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

    2020-06-22T23:51:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-22T23:51:55.344664+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh setup.sh && streamlit run waskasoo_app.py`
2020-06-22T23:51:57.304450+00:00 app[web.1]: “
2020-06-22T23:51:57.304524+00:00 app[web.1]: setup.sh: 3: setup.sh: [server]: not found
2020-06-22T23:51:57.304562+00:00 app[web.1]: setup.sh: 4: setup.sh: headless: not found
2020-06-22T23:51:57.304604+00:00 app[web.1]: setup.sh: 6: setup.sh: port: not found
2020-06-22T23:51:57.304832+00:00 app[web.1]: setup.sh: 7: setup.sh: “: not found
2020-06-22T23:51:57.353758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-06-22T23:51:57.397709+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-22T23:52:05.978572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=waskasoo-app.herokuapp.com request_id=b4a6b610-0da3-45a5-9ab9-2d348a7f26c1 fwd="174.3.224.245" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-22T23:52:06.425022+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=waskasoo-app.herokuapp.com request_id=022659a9-8c86-4688-bd5b-95d34e6851bd fwd="174.3.224.245" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: I doubt your .sh file works on local. That's not how you do a multi-line echo in Bash, and the curly quotes can't be helping. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969953/how-to-output-a-multiline-string-in-bash

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons the app wasn't loading, which when corrected works:

1. I had wrongly spelt the name of the app on the procfile
2. The setup.sh file had not been pushed correctly to git and heroku.