# How to specify a multi-line shell variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a query:

```
function print_ui_hosts
{
local sql = "select ........."
print_sql "$ sql"
}
```

local sql - a very long string. Query is not formatted.
How can I split a string into multiple lines?

Comment: What `shell` are well talking here? Should `batch` be `bash` or are you really from the darkside?

Comment: if this is shell/bash, you should not surround `=` with spaces.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Use `read` with a heredoc as shown below:

```
read -d '' sql << EOF
select c1, c2 from foo
where c1='something'
EOF

echo "$sql"
```

Comment: Note that `read` will have an exit code of 1 in this situation; if that matters (you are running with `set -e`, for example), you'll want add a `|| true` at the end of the first line.

Comment: @chepner you've saved me a year of baldness. how does `set -e` effects it? just curious.

Comment: `set -e` exits the shell if a command has an "unanticipated" non-zero exit status. By "unanticipated", I mean it runs in a context where you aren't specifically looking at its exit status. `false` by itself, for instance, would exit the shell. `false || true` would not, since you are anticipating the non-zero exit status by specifying another command to run if the first fails.

Comment: The problem with set -e and read (see last exercise) is described here in detail: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: what does `-d ' '` do here?

Comment: `read -d` appears to be a bashism, is there a way to do this in standard shell?

Comment: @hg_git Telling `read` not to stop reading when encountering a newline.

Comment: You should use 'EOF' on the first line if the multiline string isn't meant to be parsed for shell variables and the like.

Answer (score 221):

simply insert new line where necessary

```
sql="
SELECT c1, c2
from Table1, Table2
where ...
"
```

shell will be looking for the closing quotation mark

Comment: not a good solution if the sql query contains double-quotes. You will have to escape them and it will get messy.

Comment: @dogbane doublequotes appear rarely in most SQL dialects, so in practice this is clean.

Comment: Then wrap the string in single quotes.

Comment: Not sure why you want or need the leading line break.  For my application I did not so I just started with `sql="SELECT c2, c2`

Comment: Funny that it seems too easy to be true.  FYI, to add DQ, just create a variable DQ='\"' and then reference it in the statement with ${DQ}.

Comment: If answer *How can I specify a multi-line shell variable?*, then the quotation limitation is certainly a snag. Should you find yourself using different types of quotes in a string, use a here document, see `man --pager='less -p here-documents' bash` and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15429426/1236128.

Comment: Note: you've got to do echo -n "$sql" to get this out right

Comment: To avoid prepending a newline (while maintaining alignment), put a backslash (\\) on the first line. Verified identical variable contents with `hexdump -C` and it works on POSIX sh.

Answer (score 96):

I would like to give one additional answer, while the other ones will suffice in most cases.

I wanted to write a string over multiple lines, but its contents needed to be single-line.

```
sql="                       \
SELECT c1, c2               \
from Table1, ${TABLE2}      \
where ...                   \
"
```

I am sorry if this if a bit off-topic (I did not need this for SQL). However, this post comes up among the first results when searching for multi-line shell variables and an additional answer seemed appropriate.

Comment: Even without the \'s my content is coming out on one line.

Comment: @papiro, try `echo "$sql"` instead of `echo $sql`.

Comment: @MichaelMol -- About two decades after my first Linux install and I still learn something new.  Thanks for this "trick".

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to [dimo414's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35049057/26510), this shows how his great solution works, and shows that you can have quotes and variables in the text easily as well:

#### example output

```
$ ./test.sh

The text from the example function is:
  Welcome dev: Would you "like" to know how many 'files' there are in /tmp?

  There are "      38" files in /tmp, according to the "wc" command
```

#### test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function text1()
{
  COUNT=$(\ls /tmp | wc -l)
cat <<EOF

  $1 Would you "like" to know how many 'files' there are in /tmp?

  There are "$COUNT" files in /tmp, according to the "wc" command

EOF
}

function main()
{
  OUT=$(text1 "Welcome dev:")
  echo "The text from the example function is: $OUT"
}

main
```

Answer (score 6):

`read` does not export the variable (which is a good thing most of the time). Here's an alternative which can be exported in one command, can preserve or discard linefeeds, and allows mixing of quoting-styles as needed. Works for bash and zsh.

```
oneLine=$(printf %s \
    a   \
    " b "   \
    $'\tc\t'    \
    'd '    \
)
multiLine=$(printf '%s\n' \
    a   \
    " b "   \
    $'\tc\t'    \
    'd '    \
)
```

I admit the need for quoting makes this ugly for SQL, but it answers the (more generally expressed) question in the title.

I use it like this

```
export LS_COLORS=$(printf %s    \
    ':*rc=36:*.ini=36:*.inf=36:*.cfg=36:*~=33:*.bak=33:*$=33'   \
    ...
    ':bd=40;33;1:cd=40;33;1:or=1;31:mi=31:ex=00')
```

in a file sourced from both my `.bashrc` and `.zshrc`.