# Pass here document to other script

Tags: bash, variables, redirect, eof

I have a script a.sh build up an here document which looks like below

```
read -r -d "" message << EOF
line1
line2
line3
line4

EOF
```

then I want to pass this message (which contain four lines) to another program so I did

```
b.sh $message
```

however in b.sh I did

```
reMess=$1
cat $reMess
```

it only shows line1 not the rest 3 lines, could anyone explain what should I do to achieve this?

Second questions I changed the code in a.sh which make the message store in a file then read it from b.sh, could anyone suggest in b.sh how could I read this file in a here document please. code detail as  below

```
a.sh
read -r -d "" message << EOF
line1
line2
line3
line4

EOF
echo "$message" > /tmp/message.txt

b.sh
read -r -d "" information << EOF
inforation1
$(cat /tmp/message.txt)
EOF
echo "$information"
```

it return me nothing any suggestion where is wrong?
Thank you for your help

Comment: It should be `b.sh "$message"`. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1655389/171318

Comment: There's nothing obvious wrong with your second example. Did you perhaps misspell `"$information"` in the original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I see with your code is that it is needlessly complex.

```
message='line1
line2
line3
line4'

information="information1
$message"  # need double quotes rather than single to interpolate $message
```

If you don't like the embedded newlines, Bash has C-string syntax.

```
message=$'line1\nline2\nline3\nline4'
```

But there really isn't any benefit to this, and it hampers portability to other shells.  You'll get used to multi-line strings quickly.