# Using here document to give user multiple options

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

In the shell, I would like to ask the user to choose between one of two options, then when either the <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>2</kbd>, do a switch statement with it. How can I go about doing this.

```
echo "Press [1] to transfer to $drive1"
echo "Press [2] to transfer to $drive2"

read #input somehow?
```

I've tried making the second echo into a read. But ideally I'd like to put the two `echo`s into a here document, then apply that to a `read` but I could not get the lines correct.

```
options <<_EOF_

"Press [1] to transfer to $drive1"
"Press [2] to transfer to $drive2"

_EOF_
read $options -n 1
```

But I get the error `line 7: options: command not found`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to assign a heredoc value to a variable in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167746/how-to-assign-a-heredoc-value-to-a-variable-in-bash)

Comment: @EtanReisner I am looking at that page, but it seems much more complex than my question. Is there a simpler way than the selected answer's use of `read`?

Comment: What about `select drive in "${drives[@]}"; do case …; esac; done`?

Comment: Not very nice and requires a cat: `options=$( cat <<EOF .... EOF )`. I kinda like the `select` option offered by @kojiro better

Comment: Another solution would be writing the menu in a cfg file:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38200/ksh-styling-text-based-menu-using-stderr/115371#115371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do two things:

1. Write a message to the user
2. Read a number

These are two entirely separate operations, and you shouldn't try to combine them. To write out a message in a here doc, use `cat`:

```
cat << EOF
Press [1] to transfer to $drive1
Press [2] to transfer to $drive2

EOF
```

To read a number:

```
read -n 1 option
```

Here all together:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF
Press [1] to transfer to $drive1
Press [2] to transfer to $drive2

EOF

read -n 1 option

echo
echo "You entered: $option"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. If anyone sees this in the future, be advised that copy/pasting from SO is going to get you a lot of whitespace after the `EOF`s, which will break the heredoc so you'll have to delete it. Thanks again man.

Comment: @1252748 I removed the whitespaces, peer review pending... This is not always the case, but happened this time

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do

```
cat << PROMPT
Press [1] to transfer to $drive1
Press [2] to transfer to $drive2
PROMPT
read -n1 drivenumber
case "$drivenumber" in
    1) handle drive 1;;
    2) handle drive 2;;
    *) handle invalid input;;
esac
```

That would suit your stated requirements. But you have to do extra work to avoid invalid inputs:

```
input=
while true; do
    that whole thing
    validate_input && break
    echo "oh no your input was invalid"
done
```

Further, to clarify my `select` comment above, the architecture implied by using a heredoc is a little cumbersome when you want to change the number of drives.

```
drives=( "$drive1" "$drive2" )
PS3="Choose a drive to transfer to"
select drive in "${drives[@]}"; do
    # really no need for a case statement anymore
    do_x_to "$drive"
done
```

Or you could take the hybrid road:

```
while true; do
    for i in "${!drives[@]}"; do
        printf 'Press [%d] to transfer to %s\n' "$i" "${drives[i]}"
    done
    read -n1 drive_number
    if [[ ! ${drives[drive_number]} ]]; then
        echo "invalid drive number" >&2
        continue
    fi
    drive=${drives[drive_number]}
    case "$drive" in …
    esac
done
```