# Handling python output data in a bash script

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash script which goes out,does some DNS queries and returns an IP address value which I assign as a variable $external

I want to take this variable from the bash script and feed it into python and do some subnet intelligence but I'm not sure how to handle the data after this and pass it back to bash.

I can see that the **$external** variable is being passed from bash into python ok but this is where I'm not sure what to do next. (thanks Farhan.K for assisting me with what I have already)

```
python3 <<END
import ipaddress
ipsub = {"10.10.10.0/24": "Firewall-Denver", "10.10.20.0/25": "FirewallNewYork"}
iplist = [$external]

ipfirewall = []


for i in ipsub:
    for j in iplist:
        if ipaddress.ip_address(j) in ipaddress.ip_network(i):
            ipfirewall.append([j,ipsub[i]])

 END
```

The following would write it to a file:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
file.writelines('\t'.join(i) + '\n' for i in ipfirewall)
```

But how to I pass it back to bash in the same format?

Thanks in advance for your advice and assitance.

Comment: You can simply write to standard output and capture that in a shell variable or operate on it in a pipeline. Is that the question? Also it might be better to have your python script take a command line argument instead of expanding a variable into the script directly (safer and cleaner this way).

Comment: this is very confusing. Why do you need to pass values back and forth between bash and python? Why not trying a "pure" python program, and if there is some bash functionality, call it from there passing values ofer stdout?

Comment: Have you simply tried `sys.stdout.writelines()` and accepting input from stdin in the bash script?

Comment: Rafael T - Unfortunately there has already been loads of development done in bash already and I want to use the ipaddress function in python.

Comment: Passing a value as `sys.argv[1]` would be a lot more robust than interpolating text into a here document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by writing the intended result to Python's standard output, and capturing the result in a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

external="'10.10.10.1','10.10.20.1'"

result="$(python3 <<END
import ipaddress
ipsub = {"10.10.10.0/24": "Firewall-Denver", "10.10.20.0/25": "FirewallNewYork"}
iplist = [$external]

ipfirewall = []


for i in ipsub:
    for j in iplist:
        if ipaddress.ip_address(j) in ipaddress.ip_network(i):
            ipfirewall.append([j,ipsub[i]])
print(ipfirewall)
END
)"

echo "$result"
```

In the above script, I pass `$external` into the Python heredoc, run your process, and print the result in Python. The `$()` construct captures the standard output of the Python script into a Bash variable.

For the more generic version of this question, see [How to assign a heredoc value to a variable in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167746/how-to-assign-a-heredoc-value-to-a-variable-in-bash)

Comment: Though you should use double quotes in `echo "$result"`

Comment: I don't seem to be able to return what comes back from the for loop

Comment: I've modified the script to more closely mirror your original code, which should help.

Comment: Thanks you very much!