# How to export a function in ksh ? Without global declaration or using autoload

Tags: linux, export, ksh

I have a function. I need to use it in parallel calls. for that I need to export the function first in ksh, which O am not able to. export -f or export -q, nothing is working really.

Comment: I do not understand your requirements. Can you write the function in a special "utility" file and `source` that file in different scripts?

Answer (score 1):

> export -f or export -q, nothing is working really.

That's no wonder - `ksh`'s `export` doesn't have such options.

Moreover, [man ksh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh):

> The export attribute of functions is currently not used.

If you don't want to use the provided means `ENV` and `FPATH`, your wish is unsatisfiable.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda late, but I had the same issue.  So what I did was, I put my functions into a variable, and then exported the variable.  In the contexts where I want the function inside of the variable, I `eval` the variable.

Also, you can define the function in a here document and put them into an variable as seen in this question [How to assign a heredoc value to a variable in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167746/how-to-assign-a-heredoc-value-to-a-variable-in-bash).

Stupid right?  Well, it works.  What a kludge. :/

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `ksh`, then simply write `export function_name` without any options. I tried it, and it worked for me.

For example

```
function foo {
   #some linux scripting
}

export foo
```

That's it...

Comment: doesn't work in zsh