# Use of a HEREDOC with SLURM sbatch --wrap

Tags: bash, heredoc, slurm, sbatch

I am encountering difficulties using a (Bash) HEREDOC with a SLURM `sbatch` submission, via `--wrap`.

I would like the following to work:

```
SBATCH_PARAMS=('--nodes=1' '--time=24:00:00' '--mem=64000' '--mail-type=ALL')

sbatch ${SBATCH_PARAMS[@]} --job-name="MWE" -o "MWE.log" --wrap <<EOF
        SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE=\${SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE:-8}
        SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK=\${SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK:-\$SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE}
        export OMP_NUM_THREADS=\$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK

        parallel --joblog "MWE-jobs.log" --resume --resume-failed -k --linebuffer -j \$((\$OMP_NUM_THREADS/4)) --link "MWE.sh {1} {2}" ::: "./"*R1*.fastq.gz ::: "./"*R2*.fastq.gz
EOF
```

---

On my current cluster, `sbatch` returns the below error, refusing to submit this job:

```
ERROR:   option --wrap requires argument
```

Might anyone know how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `wrap` expects a string argument, you can't use a heredoc directly. Heredocs are used when a filename is expected where it's undesirable to make one.

Use a heredoc for `cat`, where it does expect a filename, and use its output as the string for which `--wrap` expects:

```
SBATCH_PARAMS=('--nodes=1' '--time=24:00:00' '--mem=64000' '--mail-type=ALL')

sbatch ${SBATCH_PARAMS[@]} --job-name="MWE" -o "MWE.log" --wrap $(cat << EOF
        SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE=\${SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE:-8}
        SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK=\${SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK:-\$SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE}
        export OMP_NUM_THREADS=\$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK

        parallel --joblog "MWE-jobs.log" --resume --resume-failed -k --linebuffer -j \$((\$OMP_NUM_THREADS/4)) --link "MWE.sh {1} {2}" ::: "./"*R1*.fastq.gz ::: "./"*R2*.fastq.gz
EOF)
```

Comment: I wish I could. I've never found it, if you do, please let me know. See [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-heredoc-to-a-file-in-bash-script). `<<<` are here strings which have a similar functionality without a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the heredoc without the `wrap` provided you add the `#!/bin/bash` at the top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167746/how-to-assign-a-heredoc-value-to-a-variable-in-bash) on assigning a HEREDOC to a variable, but instead using `cat` (since I use `errexit` and want to avoid [working-around the non-zero exit value of the `read`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265484/250562)), I was able to submit my job as follows:

```
CMD_FOR_SUB=$(cat <<EOF
    SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE=\${SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE:-8}
    SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK=\${SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK:-\$SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE}
    export OMP_NUM_THREADS=\$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK

    parallel --joblog "MWE-jobs.log" --resume --resume-failed -k --linebuffer -j \$((\$OMP_NUM_THREADS/4)) --link "MWE.sh {1} {2}" ::: "./"*R1*.fastq.gz ::: "./"*R2*.fastq.gz
EOF
)

sbatch ${SBATCH_PARAMS[@]} --job-name="MWE" -o "MWE.log" --wrap "$CMD_FOR_SUB"
```

---

While this does appear to work, I would still prefer a solution that allows `sbatch` to directly accept the HEREDOC.