# How to use newline in variable with spaces

Tags: bash

I want to create a variable that contains a string of text [in BASH] that spans multiple lines and includes spaces.  I can do this without spaces, but not with spaces.

I am trying to create a flash card program for self study.  I am not in school and this is not homework.

This works:

```
$ TEST=me$'\n'you
$ echo "$TEST"
me
you
```

This does not work:

```
$ TEST="me on line one$'\n'you on line two"
$ echo "$TEST"
me on line one$'\n'you on line two
```

I would like the output of the second code to look like this:

me on line one
you on line two

Note: this is not a duplicate question.  The alleged duplicate does not contain an example with spaces, which is why I had a problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167746/how-to-assign-a-heredoc-value-to-a-variable-in-bash

Comment: Neither of those questions are duplicates to mine.  Those questions do not contain spaces in the strings, which is why I had a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ test=$'me on line one\nyou on line two'
$ echo "$test"
me on line one
you on line two
```

If you insist on using different quoting methods for different parts of the string (why?), you need something like

```
$ test="me on line one"$'\n'"you on line two"
```

Comment: Fixed my problem.  Thank you!