# How to create a Pull Request via GitHub CLI with multiple assignees?

Tags: bash, git, github-cli

I am trying to automate a pull request creation process for [GitHub](https://github.com/) using the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/).

I am currently utilizing the following script and it works like a charm:

```sh
(
  # Parentheses are used here to avoid the exposure of temporal variables to the outer scope.
  # Tested on macOS bash only.
  
  cd ~/Projects/pet_projects/basic_temperature
   
  # Pushes the release branch to the remote repository.
  git push origin release_nemo

  # Logs in to GitHub CLI using pre-generated access token.
  # https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token
  gh auth login --with-token < ~/Projects/pet_projects/.github_cli_access_token
   
# Sets HEREDOC to PR_TITLE variable.
# Indentation is avoided here intentionally.
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/1655389/12201472
read -r -d '' PR_TITLE <<-'TEXT'
This is a Placeholder PR to check whether all specs are green [Current Release][Nemo]
TEXT
 
# Sets HEREDOC to PR_BODY variable.
# Indentation is avoided here intentionally.
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/1655389/12201472
read -r -d '' PR_BODY <<-'MARKDOWN'
[RELEASE CARD TODO]() (**❗This PR is NOT completed yet!❗**)
      
### Already included cards:
- None.
 
### Cards to be included:
- None.
 
### Previous Release TODO
MARKDOWN
 
  gh pr create \
    --title "${PR_TITLE}" \
    --body "${PR_BODY}" \
    --base master \
    --head release_nemo \
    --assignee @me \
    --label Release \
    --web
)
```

The only problem which I have right now, it is not clear to me how to update this command

```sh
gh pr create \
  --title "${PR_TITLE}" \
  --body "${PR_BODY}" \
  --base master \
  --head release_nemo \
  --assignee @me \
  --label Release \
  --web
```

to assign multiple assignees to the newly created PR?

I have read the [gh pr create](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) docs carefully and I haven't found a way how to achieve it yet.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The gh command uses `github.com/spf13/cobra` for command line flag parsing, and the [`Assignees` field is a `StringSlice`](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/31cccb4604053dc966d2b67ca3112fd944c26349/pkg/cmd/pr/create/create.go#L170). According to the [cobra docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/pflag#StringSlice), you can provide the flag multiple times or separate multiple values with a comma.

So you can do `--assignee @me --assignee @you` or `--assignee @me,@you`.

Comment: camh Thank you very much for your answer, especially for providing links to sources.