# How can I make space for the last word using bash script

Tags: bash, kubernetes

```
rolebinding="apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1\nkind: RoleBinding\nmetadata:\n  name: $rolebindingname\n  namespace: $namespace\nroleRef:\n  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io\n  kind: ClusterRole\n  name: admin\nsubjects:\n- kind: ServiceAccount\n  name: $accountname"
echo -e  $rolebinding |  kubectl apply -f -
```

I want to make space at the end the script so it can be as below:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: monitoring-gitlab-rolebinding
  namespace: mdep
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: monitoring-gitlab
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two pieces to this.

The first part is properly building a multi-line string.  The following is one thread that talks about this: [How to assign a heredoc value to a variable in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167746/how-to-assign-a-heredoc-value-to-a-variable-in-bash) .

The second part is a little more subtle, if the first part wasn't subtle enough for you.

You have to echo out the value in a particular way, otherwise it won't preserve the line endings.

If the variable is "stuff", the following will echo it out preserving line endings:

```
echo "$stuff"
```

Doing it this way will lose the line endings:

```
echo $stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the variable & echo command.  Just use a "heredoc" as input to `kubectl`.  The quotes around 'EOF' preserve whitespace:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<'EOF'
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: $rolebindingname
  namespace: $namespace
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: $accountname
EOF
```